# how to convert Multiple Inheritance to a non-heirarchical Composition?

Tags: dependencies, multiple-inheritance, composite

I've recently had to start using a language that didn't have multiple inheritance for the first time, and I'm having trouble compositing objects using the composite design pattern. So, using letters to represent objects and arrows as dependencies, I only understand how to convert the following relationship into a composite:

```
    a   e
    ^   ^
b < d < h > f
    v   v    
    c   g
```

Compositing is what I've always done in that sort of situation. The problem comes when the dependencies are reversed:

```
    a   e
    v   v
b > d > h < f
    ^   ^    
    c   g
```

In the past I used virtual multiple inheritance for this, and I can't figure out how to use compositing to encapsulate that in a decent way: the dependencies keep spilling out into the calling code. And that's not even getting into situations where the dependencies can't be formed into a directed acyclic graph and form more of a loose network, which I've always found multiple inheritance encapsulates quite nicely.

When I tried to look this up all I could find was examples of the first situation mentioned, and references to the "dreaded" inheritance diamond, which is a bit confusing because getting the diamond seems to be the entire point of having multiple inheritance as far as I can tell.